# Triangulation of a weird sphere

Tags: general-topology, triangulation

I have a math test coming up tomorrow. One of the topics will be triangulation. My teacher put up some questions we could try out.I am quite stumped by one of them, however, and would love some help with it.

"Draw a different triangulation of the surface area of the sphere than the one we have drawn below, and describe them both. Let V = “number of vertices”, E = “number of edges” and F = “number of faces”. Calculate V-E+F for both triangulations of the sphere surface areas. Is there anything you notice?"
[The triangulation in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA4Yv.png)

I was wondering if you guys could help me calculate Euler's Characteristic for the figure in question, and maybe help me draw another triangulation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : fix a triangulation $t$. What happened if you subdivide your triangulation with only one more triangle ? Can you always relate two triangulations ?

Comment: I really am not very familiar with triangulation at all, so I'm in doubt as to how to subdivide it. Sorry! :/

Comment: If you have two triangulations, you can take a triangulation which refines both of your previous triangulations : take all the set of vertices and edges. If they intersect, create new vertices. So it is enough to see if $t$ refines $t'$ then the Euler characteristic agree.

Comment: Ok and concerning your picture : this is clear that $\chi(t) = 2$ since there are $2$ $2$-cells, $1$ $1$-cell and $1$ $0$cell, and $2 - 1 + 1 = 2$.

Comment: So I could actually just draw any sphere, and that would be an appropriate triangulation of my figure?

Also, I'm not familiar with the terms 2-cells, 1-cells and 0-cells. What do you mean by those? Thanks again!

Comment: I am sorry your question is a bit too vague and I don't have much time to discuss about the whole theory. A triangulation is the data of edges (1-cells), vertices (0-cells)  and triangles (2-cells) satisfying some conditions. Euler characteristic is $V - E + T$ which is clearly $2$ in your picture. You can try to triangulate the sphere in another way and count it again. It will not depends of the triangulations, and I sketched how to prove it.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I helped, good luck for your test :)